# Wifi Direct Group Owner Address

Tags: wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager

That's an easy question, I've to get the "Group Owner address" using "Wifi direct", I know that this is in WifiP2pInfo.GroupOwnerAddress, but how can I initialize WifiP2pInfo.groupOnwerAddress to get the Group Owner address in my application?

Could someone give me a pass to pass?
I'm new in android and java.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(extraKey);

  if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    wifiP2pManager.requestConnectionInfo(wifiDirectChannel, 
      new ConnectionInfoListener() {
        public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) { 


            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(class.this,info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress().toString, Toast.LENGHT_SHORT); 
            toast.show();    

        }
      }
  }
```

Sorry for late answer.
This is owner IP `info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress().toString`

Answer (score 1):

Group owner IP address in wifi direct is always constant, i.e., 192.168.49.1. To check this, you can make following changes in your BroadcastReceiver class.

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

                    if (mManager == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                            .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);


                    if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                        mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, new ConnectionInfoListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {

                                InetAddress groupOwnerAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress;


                                String s=groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
                                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Server IP Address "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: The Group owner address is only 192.168.49.1 if the group owner is an Android device.  There is no requirement in the spec (or guarantee for future Android versions) that it will be set to this value.